# The intersection points are collinear

Tags: geometry, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, algebraic-curves

It is given a hexagon inscribed in a conic section.

I want to prove that the pairs of opposite site intersect at three points of the projective plane that are collinear.

How could  we do this? Could you give me some hints?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Cayley-Bacharach theorem? It states that if two conics intersect at 9 points, then any third conic through 8 of the points also hits the 9th one.

Comment: @Nate Yes, how could we use this?

Comment: Terry Tao have a blog post about this and in particular answers your question, [see here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/pappuss-theorem-and-elliptic-curves/).

Answer (score 2):

Oops I said conic when I meant cubic.  Anyway, here is an expansion on my comment. Let the first cubic be the lines defined by the first, third, and fifth sides of the hexagon. Let the second cubic be the lines defined by the remaining sides.  These two conics intersect at the 6 vertices of the hexagon and the three points you care about.  Now let the third cubic be the conic and a line through two of the points you care about.  This contains 8 of the 9 points I mentioned, so by Cayley-Bacharach it must contain the ninth.

Comment: Could you explain me further the idea?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link for a beautiful paper by Eisenbud, Harris, and Green:

***Eisenbud, David; Green, Mark; Harris, Joe: Cayley-Bacharach theorems and conjectures. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 33 (1996), no. 3, 295–324.***

See *Theorem CB1*, *Theorem CB2*, and *Theorem CB3*. The question you asked is actually Theorem CB2.

Comment: I don't have this book... Could you explain me the general idea?

Comment: @evinda: this is not a book. this is a paper. here is a link for the paper: https://www.msri.org/~de/papers/pdfs/1996-001.pdf